# Why when upgrading civi via drush I always get You are already upgraded to CiviCRM version-I'm-upgrading-from?

Tags: upgrade, drush

I saw a bug out there on this but it's old and claims to be fixed.  I keep thinking the next time I do an upgrade, it'll be fixed.

So for example:  upgrading from 5.9.1 to 5.10.0

```
drush civicrm-upgrade --tarfile=~/civicrm-5.10.0-drupal.tar.gz
```

Which outputs a bunch of normal messages and then

```
You are already upgraded to CiviCRM 5.9.1
```

Which is true, but I'm trying to upgrade to 5.10.  When I run the exact same command again, it works.

Comment: Just did a test upgrade from 5.20.0 to 5.21.1 and it did this again but this time running it again is all bad.  It's already unzip the tarfile so it doesn't find it but goes ahead and deletes sites/all/modules/civicrm and since there is no tar file it bombs.  Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug or does no one really use drush to upgrade or do I need the secret decoder riing or...